# Is it possible to set a session time out for a specific user?

Tags: community, salesforce1-app, session, timeout

My question is simple

Is it possible to set a session time out for a specific user in salesforce?

Not a profile ,not a permission set but a specific user..

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

I don't think it is possible. Meanwhile you can upvote this idea [Session Timeout settings for a specific user](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000kwgTAAQ).

Answer (score 0):

No, it is set globally for the Salesforce org not the individual users.

Comment: Also we can set the timeout for profile level.